# debian packaging - cmake project

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, package, debian

I am building a package from a cmake project organized in 2 source directories:

When building manually I have to go in the 2 src dirs and do:

```
cd src1
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
etc.

cd src2
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
etc.
```

Now translated into a debian/rules files I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
export DH_OPTIONS
export DH_VERBOSE=1

%:
   dh "$@" -Dsrc1 --buildsystem=cmake
   dh "$@" -Dsrc2 --buildsystem=cmake
```

This does not work and only builds package with src1. Any hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `dh` command automatically detects the `buildsystem`. I recommend you to check the man pages of `dh`.

```
man dh
```

You can try this code in your `debian/rules` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
    dh  $@ --sourcedirectory=src1
    dh  $@ --sourcedirectory=src2
```

Indent the `dh` lines with tabs, not with spaces because of makefile syntax.